# Batch script to hide Windows 10 Activation notifications

Tags: windows, batch-file, activation, ncr, aloha

I wrote this batch script for one (and more) of our clients using NCR Aloha in their business. 
After their end of day occurs, the activation message reappears. Problem being is that I set up a scheduled task to run this file after their EOD but its inconsistent as to when it works. Its working for one client but not the others we have tested with.

When their terminals leave our office, their File server has windows 10 activated but when their Terminals are installed on their site, they keep throwing the windows activation notification. The sites are all internal networks except for the File server. If I run this batch and capture the image with the reg edits in place theoretically will this stick on their EOD image?

Thanks!

```
@echo off

REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > WindowsNT > CurrentVersion > SoftwareProtectionPlatform > Activation /v Manual /t REG_DWORD /d 1
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop /v PaintDesktopVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 0

shutdown /r

exit
```

Comment: Why did you post this question, then delete [your previous duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59185459) from two weeks ago? Anyhow, currently what you've posted is incorrect syntax, please open a Command Prompt window and enter `reg add /?` to read how to use the command properly. I would strongly suggest that you contact Microsoft, if you've got issues with activation, you've paid for, not try to hack the registry.

Comment: Also, depending upon which profile/user your scheduled task runs as, I doubt that the Current User change will do what you're expecting, especially because elevated permissions will be required for the Local Machine change.